# How to determine level curves/contours of a 3D function?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I have the function $f(x,y) = e^{y/x^2}$ and I need to draw a contour map for levels $e^{-2}$, $e^{-1}$, $1$, $e$, and $e^2$.

I set $e^{-2}$ equal to the function, and solved for $y$ so that $y = -2x^2$.

Isn't this curve impossible? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your work is correct.  What do you mean when you say that $y=-2x^2$ is impossible?

Comment: How can the graph be negative when e^x cannot be negative for any value of x?

Comment: We're not asking $e^x$ to be negative.  What your work shows is that for (almost) any pair $(x,y)$ on the curve $y=-2x^2$, $f(x,y)=e^2$.  That is, the curve $y=-2x^2$ gives a solution set to the equation $f(x,y)=e^2$.  The one exception is the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: Correction: $f(x,y)=e^2$ should be $f(x,y)=e^{-2}$ in both instances above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lucky in the sense that $f(t)=e^{t}$ is an invertible function. That means that you can just set the argument equal to each other just like you have done. But you would not have been allowed to do so if it wasn't invertible!

For example if you set $(x)^2=(-1)^2$ you can't just assume $x=-1$, because $f(t)=t^2$ is not invertible. You won't catch all solutions then.